# Adding user to different group with different required field

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-user-groups

Scenario: Jomla 3.3 + CB 2.3 + CB Profile PRO + JFBConnect

Target:
Free user registration to Group A or/and group B also in two different timeframe.

- Group A (simple Joomla registration): Login with FB account (required field: username + email + FBid)
- GROUP B: (required field: field3+field4+field5...)

To switch from group A to group B the user has to fill all required field.

Problem:

- If I set all fields as required they are required also in the basic registration form (Group A)
- If I don't set the Group B filed as required, users can switch to Group B witout filling all fields.

Any tips?
thx

Comment: How are you currently setting the fields as required?

Comment: No,they aren't set as required. If I set as required then also group A users have to fill all fields to register.

Comment: I am not aware of CB, but [Joom profile](http://www.function90.com/docs/field-accessibility-in-joom-profile.html) has this functionality. But it doesn't have Facebook Connect sort of.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Looks like the solution is CB autogroup + CB Conditional

I used CB Autogrup to lets users choose their preferred Group, and CB Conditional to set specific required fields based on the users choise.

Es.:

1) Create in Joompa Group: GroupA and GroupB

2) create in CB fields fieldprofile -> Group A, Group B

Use CB Autogrup to associate joomla Group and fieldprofile value

Use CB conditional to set the rules based on the fieldprofile value

es.: if fieldprofile value NOT GroupB than hide all GroupB related fields else shows as required all GroupB related fields.

Read the plugin components docs for more info

Comment: Please consider improving your answer by adding more details.